# SQL Server how to select first row in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table with the following sample data:

```
Tag          Loc        Time1
A            10         6/2/15 8:00 AM
A            10         6/2/15 7:50 AM
A            10         6/2/15 7:30 AM
A            20         6/2/15 7:20 AM
A            20         6/2/15 7:15 AM
B            10         6/2/15 7:12 AM
B            10         6/2/15 7:11 AM
A            10         6/2/15 7:10 AM
A            10         6/2/15 7:00 AM
```

I need  SQL to select the first (earliest) row in a sequence until location changes, then select the earliest row again until location changes.  In other words I need the following output from above:

```
Tag         Loc         Time1
A           10          6/2/15 7:30 AM
A           20          6/2/15 7:15 AM
A           10          6/2/15 7:00 AM
B           10          6/2/15 7:11 AM
```

I tried this from Giorgos - but some lines from the select were duplicated:

```
declare @temptbl table (rowid int primary key identity, tag nvarchar(1), loc int, time1 datetime)
declare @tag as nvarchar(1), @loc as int, @time1 as datetime

insert into @temptbl (tag, loc, time1) values (1,20,'6/5/2015 7:15 AM')
insert into @temptbl (tag, loc, time1) values (1,20,'6/5/2015 7:20 AM')
insert into @temptbl (tag, loc, time1) values (1,20,'6/5/2015 7:25 AM')
insert into @temptbl (tag, loc, time1) values (4,20,'6/5/2015 7:20 AM')
insert into @temptbl (tag, loc, time1) values (4,20,'6/5/2015 7:25 AM')
insert into @temptbl (tag, loc, time1) values (4,20,'6/5/2015 7:30 AM')
insert into @temptbl (tag, loc, time1) values (4,20,'6/5/2015 7:35 AM')
insert into @temptbl (tag, loc, time1) values (4,20,'6/5/2015 7:40 AM')

select * from @temptbl

SELECT Tag, Loc, MIN(Time1) as time2
FROM (
SELECT Tag, Loc, Time1,      
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Time1) - 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Tag, Loc 
                          ORDER BY Time1) AS grp
FROM @temptbl ) t

GROUP BY Tag, Loc, grp
```

Here is the results (there should only be one line for each tag)

```
Tag  Loc time2
1   20  2015-06-05 07:15:00.000
1   20  2015-06-05 07:25:00.000
4   20  2015-06-05 07:20:00.000
4   20  2015-06-05 07:30:00.000
```

Comment: use loop and check in each step the next row has Loc same if not take it likewise you can do this. use rownumber also so it will be more simple

Comment: I've tried various combinations using row_number() over partition, but no success

Comment: no success means ? you did not get row number ?? or any other error ?

Comment: Also thanks Mureinik for correcting my post - this is my first on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Can you check my updated answer and see if it works ?

Comment: Why is "A           10          6/2/15 7:00 AM" row before "B           10          6/2/15 7:11 AM" row in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this, change `yourTable` with table name you want

```
declare @temptbl table (rowid int primary key identity, tag nvarchar(1), loc int, time1 datetime)

declare @tag as nvarchar(1), @loc as int, @time1 as datetime

declare tempcur cursor for 
select tag, loc, time1
from YourTable
-- order here by time or whatever columns you want to

open tempcur

fetch next from tempcur
into @tag, @loc, @time1

while (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
    if not exists (select top 1 * from @temptbl where tag = @tag and loc = @loc and rowid = (select max(rowid) from @temptbl))
    begin
        print 'insert'
        print @tag
        print @loc
        print @time1
        insert into @temptbl (tag, loc, time1) values (@tag, @loc, @time1)
    end
    else
    begin
        print 'update'
        print @tag
        print @loc
        print @time1
        update @temptbl
        set tag = @tag,
            loc = @loc,
            time1 = @time1
         where tag = @tag and loc = @loc and rowid = (select max(rowid) from @temptbl)
    end


    fetch next from tempcur
    into @tag, @loc, @time1
end

deallocate tempcur

select * from @temptbl
```

Comment: why you need cursor here ?using cursor here  is  a bad practice

Comment: How you decided that ?

Comment: Because cursors take up memory and sometimes create locks.it will affect the performance

Comment: **Sometimes**.. do you see that sometimes in this query? don't make assumptions based on common views. + How can it create lock if i'm not using user table in cursor ? Explain.

Comment: i am not asking about this query. i just say the common behavior. normally it is not a good practice when you are using cursor   you are basically loading those rows into memory

Comment: 'Normally not using' doesn't mean 'never using'. Also about memory point you brought up, things are same with temp table, CTEs, hash tables.

Comment: just try with cursor and cte and find which one works more faster.

Comment: This worked great.  For me, performance is not a key consideration in this instance, so this was what I needed!  Thank You All

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using MS SQL Server 2012 or newer, the [`lag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) window function will allow you to compare a row to the previous one:

```
SELECT tag, loc, time1
FROM   (SELECT tag, loc, time1,
               LAG (loc) OVER (PARTITION BY tag ORDER BY time1) AS lagloc
        FROM   my_table) t 
WHERE  loc != lagloc OR lagloc IS NULL
```

Comment: this is a new information for me. +1 for your valid information

Comment: If the OP is using mssql 2012

Comment: @Arion indeed, this is only available since SQL Server 2012. Since it's been available for over three years I just assumed that OP wasn't using anything older, but you're right, that's a bad assumption. I'll edit my answer to include this information.

Comment: @Mureinik : +1 : Now it contains the necessary information

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using SQL Server in Azure but I am getting the error Lag is not supported in this version of SQL server.  It shows version 11.0.9230

Comment: @Mureinik I think you need a subquery to actually implement your idea. As far as I know windowed functions can only appear in the `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos yes, that's correct, forgot about it. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

This is an alternative solution in case your use versions prior to SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT Tag, Loc, MIN(Time1)
FROM (
SELECT Tag, Loc, Time1,      
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Time1) - 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Tag, Loc 
                          ORDER BY Time1) AS grp
FROM mytable ) t
GROUP BY Tag, Loc, grp
```

It should work for SQL Server 2005+.

`ROW_NUMBER()` is used in order to identify *islands* of *successive* `Tag`, `Loc` records: `grp` will hold the *same* value for all records that belong to the same group.

**EDIT:** In case table row ordering is **not** based on `Time1` column, then `Time1` must be substituted by whatever column specifies row order, e.g. an auto-increment PK.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ea09/2)

Comment: @dennishonanFamily I thought `Time1` field could be used in order to deduce row ordering. This is not the case as it seems (after your edit). You can simply substitute `Time1` by `rowid` in `ROW_NUMBER` functions to get desired result.

Comment: Probably the first ROW_NUMBER() just needs either `PARTITION BY Tag` (if `Time1` is unique per `Tag`) or `PARTITION BY Loc` (if it's unique per `Loc`, accordingly).

Comment: @AndriyM I don't think either of these will work. This is a typical island identification problem. In this case the first `ROW_NUMBER` must return row order. An `ORDER BY` whatever column specifies table-level row order is required.

Comment: `PARTITION BY Tag` [does work](http://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/322351) though. Re-reading the question, I now think that's the right one of the two. OP says, "select the first (earliest) row in a sequence until location changes, then select the earliest row again until location changes". They never mention a tag there – because by "sequence" they mean a subset with the same tag? Not sure but works for me as an explanation. Their expected result seems to confirm that for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Please give a try on this:

```
; with t --Samples
as (
select *
from (values 
('A',            10         ,'6/2/15 8:00 AM')
, ('A',            10         ,'6/2/15 7:50 AM')
, ('A',            10         ,'6/2/15 7:30 AM')
, ('A',            20         ,'6/2/15 7:20 AM')
, ('A',            20         ,'6/2/15 7:15 AM')
, ('B',            10         ,'6/2/15 7:12 AM')
, ('B',            10         ,'6/2/15 7:11 AM')
, ('A',            10         ,'6/2/15 7:10 AM')
, ('A',            10         ,'6/2/15 7:00 AM')
) t(Tag, Loc, Time1)
)
, t2 --get the origin order
as (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) OriginOrder
from t)
, t3 --detect the tag, and loc changes (last row in group)
as (
select t2.*
from t2
    left join t2 t on t.OriginOrder=t2.OriginOrder+1 --get the next row
where not(t2.Tag = t.Tag and t2.Loc = t.Loc) --the next row has other tag and/or loc
    or (t.OriginOrder is null) --or there isn't next row
)
, t4 --make the groups about the next row
as (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by t3.OriginOrder) GroupOrder
from t3
)
, t5 --detect the tag, and loc changes (first row in group)
as (
select t2.*
from t2
    left join t2 t on t.OriginOrder=t2.OriginOrder-1 --get the previous row
where not(t2.Tag = t.Tag and t2.Loc = t.Loc) --the previous row has other tag and/or loc
    or (t.OriginOrder is null) --or there isn't previous row
)
, t6 --make the groups about the previous row
as (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by t5.OriginOrder) GroupOrder
from t5
)
--The result
select t2.Tag, t2.Loc, t2.Time1
from t4 
    join t6 on t4.GroupOrder=t6.GroupOrder
    cross apply (select top 1 * from t2 where t2.OriginOrder between t6.OriginOrder and t4.OriginOrder order by t2.Time1) t2
```

I comment my query, so I think it is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

In thinking about this, I wondered if there was a way to do it without using cursor.  This seems to work:

```
SELECT t1.tag, t1.loc, t1.time1 
FROM( 
     SELECT tag, loc, time1, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY tag ORDER by tag, 
     time1) AS row1 
     FROM @temptbl) t1
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT tag, loc, time1, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY tag ORDER by tag, 
     time1) AS row1 
     FROM @temptbl) t2
ON t1.row1=t2.row1+1 AND t1.tag=t2.tag
WHERE t2.tag IS NULL OR t1.loc <> t2.loc
ORDER BY tag, time1 DESC
```

Comment: You could also try a [modified version of Giorgos Betsos's solution](http://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/322351) (see discussion under his answer).